# how to notify observer with 2 arguments change?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm new with design patterns.

I'm trying to solve this exercise with *Java* about *Observer* design pattern:
we have a *Point* class and a *Segment* class:

```
Point{
    void translater(int dx,int dy);
    double distance(Point p);
}

Segment{
    private double longueur;
    public Segment(Point ex1,Point ex2){....longueur=ex1.distance(ex2);}

    public double getLongueur(){}
}
```

If we do `p.translater` *x* and *y* of the point change, I want the *Segment* class to be notified.

How can I notify *observer* with the *x* and *y* values?

**Note**: I must not change the `getLongueur` method.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a list of observers in Point class: in your case, a list of Segments.

```
List<Segment> observers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Than create the following methods

```
void addObserver(Segment segment)
{
    observers.add(segment);
}

void notifyAll()
{
    for (Segment observer: observers)
        observer.notify()
}
```

In `translater` method, add

```
notifyAll();
```

In Segment add the `notify` method

```
void notify()
{
    longueur=ex1.distance(ex2);
}
```

and add in the constructor the following lines

```
ex1.addObserver(this);
ex2.addObserver(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions:

1. Register the `Segment` as a listener for changes in the `Point` class.
2. Use `java.util.Observer` and `java.util.Observable`.
3. Use AOP (aspect oriented) notification of the `Segment` for calls to the `Point.translater` method.

Option 1 (the simple implementation version):

- Create a `Listener` Interface.  A simply notify method is fine; no parameter needed for this simple implementation.
- Change `Segment` to implement the `Listener` interface.
- Change `Point` to store a `List` of `Listener` references.
- Add a `addListener` method to `Point`.
- Add a `removeListener` method to `Point` (optional).
- In the `Segment` constructor, register the segment as a listener with each of the `Point` objects.
- Store a `List` of `Point` references in the `Segment` class.  Set these in the constructor.  Maybe must store ex1 and ex2 in the `Segment` class.
- Change the `Point.translater` method to call the `Listener.notify` method for each registered listener.`
- Implement the `notify` method in `Segment` to recalculate the `longueur` value when called.

Option 2: do the same as above, but use the `java.util.Observer` interface instead of your own `Listener` interface and have `Point` implement `java.util.Observable`.

Option 3: AOP seems like overkill.  I leave this solution to the student to resolve.